# Passing ArrayList<Bitmap> into another class and convert to Bitmap[]

Tags: android

I fetch the image URL from my PHP and MySQL database. Everything here is fine, because the `Log.d` shows the result with a valid image URL.

```
if (success == 1) {
    JSONArray comments = json.getJSONArray("photos");
    for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject m = comments.getJSONObject(i);
        final String filename = m.getString("filename");
        final String extension = m.getString("extension");
        String upload_at = m.getString("upload_at");
        String uid = m.getString("uid");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap mThumbIds = fetchImage(filepath_min
                + filename + "." + extension);
        Log.d("Photo URL", filepath_min + filename + "." + extension);
                List<Bitmap> l = Arrays.asList(mThumbIds);
                photoList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(l);
            }
        });
    }
}

// Instance of ImageAdapter Class
mHandler.postDelayed((new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        imgGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(
        PhotoViewerActivity.this, photoList));
    }
}), 1000);
```

Below this for fetch an image from the given URL and return as Bitmap.
Nothing problem here, just for reference want to show that the return is Bitmap.

```
public Bitmap fetchImage(String urlstr) {
    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL(urlstr);

        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setDoInput(true);
        c.connect();
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
        Bitmap img;
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return img;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage passed invalid URL: "
        + urlstr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage IO exception: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my ImageAdapter for viewing image in GridView.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    List<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<Bitmap> l;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> l) {
        mContext = c;
        list = l;
    }

    public Bitmap[] mThumbIds = list.toArray(new Bitmap[list.size()]);

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Here is my problem. None image shown on the activity.
When I try hardcoded URL with fetch array in Bitmap[] mThumbIds, its was success.

```
Bitmap[] mThumbIds = { fetchImage("http://...jpg"),
                       fetchImage("http://...jpg") }
```

I don't know what's wrong. I've tried `Bitmap[] mThumbIds = list.toArray(new Bitmap[list.size()]);` to convert ArrayList to Array.

Comment: you have a good reasons to send `Array` of `Bitmap`? why not just send the array of URL's and do loading of images in the adapter(Lazy Loading). As bitmap of `Array` is a lot on memory.

Comment: So, you mean to send array of String URL's and fetch the image inside ImageAdapter class? OK, I give it try.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have mThumbIds declared as a regular Bitmap not a Bitmap array in your runOnUiThread method.

```
Bitmap mThumbIds = fetchImage(filepath_min + filename + "." + extension);
```

Try changing it to

```
Bitmap[] mThumbIds = fetchImage(filepath_min + filename + "." + extension);
```

Otherwise use a different variable name for the Bitmap array so you dont have conflicting variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `Bitmap mThumbIds` in `runOnUiThread` is not array yet. Then I put it as array list after that: `List<Bitmap> l = Arrays.asList(thumbs); photoList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(l);` I also tried to use different variable name but nothing happen.

Comment: At that point I would have to agree with M Moshin Naeem. It might be easier and more memory friendly just to create it as an ArrayList from the beginning so you don't have to create more and more arrays. Is there a reason your create the Array then try to convert to ArrayList?

Comment: I dont really know this Android array things work. Some as `Array`, `List` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/thest1/LazyList 
and just small change in "getView" of LazyAdapter,

Replace  `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);`

To   `imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), imageView);`

Here **data** is the `ArrayList` of URLs, which you are giving to adapter.

And in ImageLoader class, there is the method `private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)` set the size of bitmap as you want.

Comment: `just small changes` - it would be better to descibe that small changes along with code.